# Perl modules with native libs: Possible to get XSLoader to use RTLD_GLOBAL on dlopen?

Tags: c++, c, perl

The title gives the short version; the long of it is I have a C++ API wrapped to C & exposed to Perl via XS. This has worked fine for a number of years, but we have now run into a use-case that we suspect may be caused by a duplicate load of a common library.

The symptom is we have an in-house Perl wrapper around Tibrv. And, we've a wrapper around another C++ API that internally uses Tibrv. When a Perl script uses both of these APIs, the second hangs on creating a Tib transport.  Individually, both work from Perl.

I suspect, but have nothing to back this up, that it somehow has to do with shared state and Perl, by default loading libraries with `RTLD_LOCAL` set, may be causing the issue (this is a pure hunch).  I have nothing to back this up with, but I know Tib is very aware of it surroundings, I think it could be a possibility.

**My question:**
Is it possible to use `dlopen` flags, such as `RTLD_GLOBAL` with Perl's `XSLoader`? i.e. Can one change the `dlopen` flags when a native lib is opened without rebuilding Perl/XS?

Everything I've seen online so far seems to indicate you need to use DynaLoader, which would require us to rebuild our lib (because of the means in which we export our C++ symbols) in a manner suitable for use from DynaLoader (which it currently is not).

I'm only about 10% certain that this would even solve the real problem, but **knowing if we can override the `dlopen` flags easily would allow us to possibly save a few days effort**.

Answer (score 2):

XSLoader is just a front-end for DynaLoader.

Sounds like you can add

```
sub dl_load_flags { 0x01 }
```

to your module. This gets called and passed to `dl_load_file` in `flags`, which does:

```
    if (flags & 0x01)
#ifdef RTLD_GLOBAL
        mode |= RTLD_GLOBAL;
#else
        Perl_warn(aTHX_ "Can't make loaded symbols global on this platform while loading %s",filename);
#endif
    DLDEBUG(1,PerlIO_printf(Perl_debug_log, "dl_load_file(%s,%x):\n", filename,flags));
    handle = dlopen(filename, mode) ;
```

Note that `dl_load_file` is called to load the `.so` compiled from your `.xs`. As far as I know, XSLoader/DynaLoader doesn't call `dlopen` for the libraries that object might use, such as the one with which you are having problems.

Comment: Thanks, I've passed this on to my perl guys that are having the problem. Will accept when I can verify.